# Font of barButtonItem changes when highlighted swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I have a barbuttonItem here:

```
  let doneBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem? = {
    let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem()
    barButtonItem.setTitleTextAttributes([
        NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont(name: "Avenir-Heavy", size: 12)!,
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.black,
        ], for: .normal)
    barButtonItem.title = "DONE"
    return barButtonItem
}()
```

Yet when i press on it, it changes to a different font. What is the property to change the font when highlighted? Thank you.

Comment: Did you try setting the attributes for other states in addition to normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
barButtonItem.setTitleTextAttributes([
        NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont(name: "Avenir-Heavy", size: 12)!,
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.black,
        ], for: .highlighted) // This line
```